# MongoDB Sensu Script(Check) not showing Metrics in Log

Tags: mongodb, authentication, monitoring, metrics, sensu

I have sensu client installed on Mongo DB server and I am executing the Mongo DB Check using [this](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/plugins/mongodb/mongodb-metrics.rb) script It Works great when my Mongodb is  configured without Authentication, But it does not show the metrics when Authentication is enabled on the Mongo DB, Though I am passing the DB Authentication Credentials correctly, but authentication works with same credential from irb prompt. What should be the fix to get the Monitoring Metric using MongoDB Authentication ?

I am using Sensu version 0.1 6 and MongoDB 2.4.11 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it,

In fact it is not an sensu-plugin issue, it was an user authentication issue with MongoDB 2.4, Mongo allows the user which is created within admin db to collect the information of other databases.

So the following simple steps solved my issue

```
rahul@rahul:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.12
connecting to: test
> use admin
switched to db admin 
> db.addUser("rahul","rahul@123")
{
"user" : "rahul",
"readOnly" : false,
"pwd" : "85a20670734aeb830a7903183bd4132f",
"_id" : ObjectId("54d88f4950e99f42d01abfe8")
}
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
>
```

Then I modified following paramaters in mongodb-metrics.rb which is freely available [here](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/plugins/mongodb/mongodb-metrics.rb)

```
  option :user,
     description: 'MongoDB user',
     long: '--user rahul',
     default: nil

  option :password,
     description: 'MongoDB password',
     long: '--password rahul@123',
     default: nil
```

and note that the following has to be unchanged

```
db_name = 'admin'
```

here I was giving db_name as 'mydb' which was going wrong

after all I can see my metrics and graphs